# Royer oscillator - frequency shifting in WPT

Tags: coupling, wireless-charging, zvs

I am having a problem with my WPT resonant application. In my circuit modified Royer oscillator feeds LC tank. Receiver coil nearby is connected to rectifier and variable resistor. I know about frequency splitting phenomena caused by strongly coupled resonant systems but it depends mainly on coils distance. I did two measurements with the same LC circuits on both sides for two different coupling factors. Royer oscillator as shown below[image]

I do not know why my Royer oscillator shifts the frequency dependently on load resistance. With k=0.1 frequency is changing slowly but in case of strongly coupled coils the curve is sharp and Mosfets are crying and seems that Royer does not know which frequency to choose. Measured values shown below [image]

In the sharp area I see destroyed sine wave on oscilloscope but highest efficiency occurs.
Do you have any explanation of frequency shifting problem in dependence on load resistance?
Thank you for you answers

Comment: Changing load affects q of circuit, thus shifting resonant point... You can have an unstable system...

Comment: Absolutely you are right... But how can I determine the circuit is not stable.? .. If I use series resonant circuit on Rx side the gradient frequency curve is not so steep and Mosfets work well..

Comment: Sorry, I only understand this effect from dealing with Tesla coils and resonant tank circuits. Not an expert on oscillators and conditional stability... off the top of my head is actually not clear to me how you could get a stable system with this type of a setup...

Comment: Actually the more I think about it isn't this referred to as frequency pulling, and the only effective way to reduce it is to buffer the output of your oscillator? Before a load?

Comment: Thank you for the answer... I think I figured it out.. Problem is that you can not tune your Rx circuit to exact the same resonant frequency as your Tx circuit  (only if we talk about strongly coupled systems) .. if you tune to the same resonant frequency two global impedance minimum occur and Royer wants to tune to global impedance minimum but can not because there are two of them so just trying to pick one and running between them... just detune Rx circuit little bit solved the problem

Comment: You should make that an answer for your question. It is good for future people.